# File not downloading from folder

Tags: asp.net

I have a problem with file download. I have a grid which shows the file name and a link to download that file. 
This is the code of my grid.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv7" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" CssClass="tbl_green_parrot"
PageSize="5" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EmptyDataText="No Scheme data available" DataKeyNames="FilePath" OnPageIndexChanging="gv7_PageIndexChanging"             onrowdatabound="gv7_RowDataBound">
  <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="tbl_green_parrot1" />
 <FooterStyle CssClass="tbl_green_parrotfoot" />
 <PagerStyle CssClass="tbl_green_parrotpager" />
 <SelectedRowStyle CssClass="tbl_green_parrotselect" />
 <EmptyDataRowStyle CssClass="tbl_green_parrotempty" />
 <Columns>
   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="File Name">
   <ItemTemplate>
   <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkFile" Target="_blank" CausesValidation="false" runat="server"
   Text='<%# Bind("DisplayName") %>' NavigateUrl='<%# Bind("FilePath") %>' />
   </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Download" ItemStyle-Width="25px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
   <ItemTemplate>
   <a id="lnkDLoad" href='<%# Bind("FilePath") %>' runat="server" target="_blank">
   <img src="Images/download.png" alt="Download" />
   </a>
   </ItemTemplate>
   <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="25px" ></ItemStyle>
   </asp:TemplateField>
 </Columns>
```

Here I bind the filepath to the `<a>` tag. This code is running when I have the file in the same root folder in the website. But when I attempt to download the file which is inside the folder it doesn't download.

The code behind for downloading:

```
DataTable new_dt = new DataTable();
    new_dt.Columns.Add("DisplayName");
    new_dt.Columns.Add("FileName");
    new_dt.Columns.Add("FilePath");
    string Query = "SELECT DisplayName,FilePath,Universal From DistScheme";
    dt = DataAccessLayer.DAL.getFromDataTable(Query);
    string filename = "";
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            DataRow new_dr = new_dt.NewRow();
            if (dt.Rows[i]["Universal"].ToString() == "False")
            {
                filename = DistributorID + "_" + dt.Rows[i]["FilePath"].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                filename = dt.Rows[i]["FilePath"].ToString();
            }
            string filepath = Server.MapPath("Uploads/Scheme/") + filename;
            if (File.Exists(filepath))
            {
                new_dr["DisplayName"] = dt.Rows[i]["DisplayName"].ToString();
                new_dr["FileName"] = filename;
                new_dr["FilePath"] = filepath;
                new_dt.Rows.Add(new_dr);
            }
        }
    }
    gv7.DataSource = new_dt;
    gv7.DataBind();
```

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file path should be start from "http". Include complete path in the filepath like http://domian-name/foldername/filename with extenssion.

Comment: you can easily check by your FTP structure where your file stored.

Comment: In my code i am using Server.MapPath() method to find the path of my file. but it gives the physical path of the file which is not downloadable. How to get the downloadable path from code. Is there any method defined to do this..?

Comment: demosite/Uploads/Scheme/Test.xls

Comment: Thanks for the rply.. now my code is working.. i was binding the whole path to the link.. but it was not required. only uploads/scheme/test.xls does my job done..

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish your task i.e. download file from grid you need to add below template column in grid as  below.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="File" SortExpression="File Path">
                <ItemTemplate>                       
                    <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="Images/download.png"  ID="imgbtnDownload" runat="server" CommandName="DOWNLOAD" Text="GetFile" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("FilePath") %>'  ></asp:ImageButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

Need to add Row_command event as below in code behind file.

```
protected void gv7_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "DOWNLOAD")
    {
    // make sure fileName  contains only file name like 'test.pdf'  
        string fileName = Convert.ToString(e.CommandArgument);

    // make sure filePath  contains file path like 'Uploads/Scheme/test.pdf'        
        string filePath = Server.MapPath(Convert.ToString(e.CommandArgument));

        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;

        // Read the original file from disk
        FileStream myFileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);
        long FileSize = myFileStream.Length;
        byte[] Buffer = new byte[Convert.ToInt32(FileSize)];
        myFileStream.Read(Buffer, 0, Convert.ToInt32(FileSize));
        myFileStream.Close();
        // Tell the browse stuff about the file
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", FileSize.ToString());
        //Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" & fileneme.Replace(" ", "_"))
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName + ";");
        //Response.TransmitFile(fileneme)
        //Response.ContentType = getMimeType(sExtention, oConnection)

        // Send the data to the browser
        Response.BinaryWrite(Buffer);
        Response.End();

    }
}
```

Now click on image button from aspx page, you can get option for open or save file.

Hope this will helps you..Happy coding...